# VPP app for business worldwide distribution

Tags: ios-appstore, volume-purchase-program

After a long submission process Apple suggested to deliver an app via VPP for business. The app is marked as "distributable worldwide", but apparently the redeem codes are enabled only for one country.

The app is designed for different users (not employee of a single company, so no 300$/year solution) which resides in different countries.

Is there a way to give the users redeem codes when they are not necessarily in the country of the VPP store?

I've asked Apple but they REALLY didn't seem to have a clear picture of their own voucher code system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After explaining a couple of times the situation, the App is now distributed on iTunes.

VPP is very country-specific, so if your client is a multi-national which has business in various countries (and some countries don't even have VPP so far, see Russia) you can still have your app published on the "public" iTunes.

Pay attention that this approval process will last at least 1 month.